# Running LEMP on Ubuntu (15.10), trying to add varnish, having problems

Tags: nginx, web-server, varnish

I seem to be having an issue with `varnish`. It's nothing major but I'm struggling to find where I may be going wrong.

Basically, `varnish` is set to run on port `6081` which it does; however. I've tried editing the `/etc/default/varnish` config and changing the `daemon_opts` to `80`, and even commented-everything out from the file, but varnish seems to still run on `6081`.

So either its not using the `/etc/default/varnish` config, and getting its settings elsewhere, or `/etc/default/varnish` isn't making any difference.

My question is does anyone know what config file it may be using to get its settings, or perhaps how I can force it to use a config? Thanks.

Comment: Post your varnish config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured a fix as it's a bug with varnish. The remainder of this post is an edited version of this article: http://deshack.net/how-to-varnish-listen-port-80-systemd/

---

Basically, `/etc/default/varnish` is only read by the `/etc/init.d/varnish script`, not by the `systemd` init script (`/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service`).

We can override the `systemd` init script of varnish and change something.

```
# cp /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service /etc/systemd/system/
# nano /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service
```

We come up with something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator

[Service]
Type=forking
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Then use either,

```
# sudo service varnish restart
```

or

```
# systemctl reload varnish.service
```

Comment: Next time don't steal content. Add attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you used right DAEMON_OPTS line. Default Varnish config has 4 examples of  DAEMON_OPTS configuration (Alternative 1, Minimal configuration; Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL; etc). If you uncommented couple of them, only last uncommented DAEMON_OPTS line will be applied.

Example:

```
## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.
# Use a 256MB memory based cache.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl.v4 \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```